# Check string for uppercase characters

Tags: excel, vba

How do I check each character in a cell to see if it is upper case?

UCASE converts letters to uppercase but I want to check.

I'm not sure where the "do" statement should go.

```vb
Function Italic(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim strng As String
    Dim iEnd As Long, iIni As Long, strngLen As Long

    strngLen = Len(rng.Value2)
    iIni = 1

    Do While iEnd <= strngLen
       Do While UCase(Mid(rng.Value, iEnd, 1)) = Mid(rng.Value, iEnd, 1) And Not rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Italic
            If iEnd = strngLen Then Exit Do
            iEnd = iEnd + 1
        Loop
        If iEnd > iIni Then strng = strng & Mid(rng.Value2, iIni, iEnd - iIni) & "|"
        iEnd = iEnd + 1
        iIni = iEnd
    Loop

    If strng <> "" Then Italic = Split(Left(strng, Len(strng) - 1), "|")

End Function
```

I'm not sure what I should do within that "uppercase".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would check if the characters uppercase equals the present character:

```
 While UCase(rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Text) = rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Text And Not rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Italic​
```

Thanks @SiddharthRoth for the assist.

Now that you have shown the full code, One more note.  You should avoid naming variables, subs and function by words that are used in excel.

So change the name to `Itlc` or something else:

```
Function Itlc(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim strng As String
    Dim iEnd As Long, iIni As Long, strngLen As Long

    strngLen = Len(rng.Value2)
    iIni = 1

    Do While iEnd <= strngLen
       Do While UCase(rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Text) = rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Text And Not rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Italic
            If iEnd = strngLen Then Exit Do
            iEnd = iEnd + 1
        Loop
        If iEnd > iIni Then strng = strng & Mid(rng.Value2, iIni, iEnd - iIni) & "|"
        iEnd = iEnd + 1
        iIni = iEnd
    Loop

    If strng <> "" Then Itlc = Split(Left(strng, Len(strng) - 1), "|")

End Function
```

Comment: When I try implementing this I get runtime error 438

Comment: I made a small change. Hope you do not mind it? You may rollback the changes if you want. @johndoe253: Try it now.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Appreciate the help.  I was working on an example.

Comment: @johndoe253 see edit. You may need to refresh the screen.

Comment: Your original code was correct. it was just missing `.Text`

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry to ask again but I have a type mismatch when the .text is in there.

Comment: @johndoe253 just did another edit.  See if that helps.  I tested it on some made up data and it seems to work for me.  Make sure that none of the cells have errors.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this quickly withut looping using a `Regexp`:

```
Function OpalsOut(StrIn As String) As Variant
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
  .Pattern = "[A-Z]+"
  .Global = True
  .ignorecase = False
If .test(StrIn) Then
    Set OpalsOut = .Execute(StrIn)
Else
    OpalsOut = "No match"""
End If
End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as this:

```
Function IsUpper(ByVal s) As Boolean
    IsUpper = UCase(s) = s
End Function
```

The idea here is to create a copy of the string and transform the copy to upper case. If the input argument string was indeed upper case to begin with then the transformed copy should now equal the input exactly.

If you have changed Excel VBA's default for comparing text values to `Option Compare Text` then you will need a different solution. But this case is rare. The above should work in Excel VBA the vast majority of times.

The following function based on RegEx is one alternative that will work even with `Option Compare Text`:

```
Function IsUpper(s) As Boolean
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "^[^a-z]*$"
        IsUpper = .Test(s)
    End With
End Function
```

And this second function will also work in Access VBA which defaults to another string comparison option.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function CheckUppercase(inpt)
    For i = 0 To Len(inpt) - 1
        nwSt = Left$(Right(inpt, Len(inpt) - i), 1)
        Select Case nwSt
            Case " ", ",", ".", ";"
                uUCase = 1
            Case Else
                If nwSt Like "*[A-Z]*" Then uUCase = 1 Else uUCase = 0: Exit For
        End Select
    Next
    If uUCase = 0 Then CheckUppercase = 0 Else CheckUppercase = 1
    ' 0 means there is lowercase inside
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function IsUpperInString(sInput As String) As Boolean
Dim sAplhabetAZ As String
Dim sCurrChar As String
Dim iLengthInput As Integer
Dim bResult As Boolean

On Error GoTo IsUpperInStringERROR

    sAplhabetAZ = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    bResult = False
    iLengthInput = Len(sInput)

    If (iLengthInput = 0) Then
       IsUpperInString = bResult
       Exit Function
    End If

    For iCounter = 1 To iLengthInput
        sCurrChar = Mid(sInput, iCounter, 1)
        If (Instr(1, sAplhabetAZ, sCurrChar, vbBinaryCompare) > 0) Then
           bResult = True
           GoTo ExitThisFunction
        End If
    Next iCounter

ExitThisFunction:

IsUpperInString = bResult

Exit Function

    IsUpperInStringERROR:
    MsgBox "Function IsUpperInStringERROR: " & Str(Err.Number) & " - " & Err.Description
    GoTo ExitThisFunction

End Function
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Function isUpperCase(parString As String) As Boolean
    Dim value As Integer
    value = Asc(Left(parString, 1))
    isUpperCase = (value >= 65 And value <= 90) Or _
                  (value >= 192 And value <= 214) Or _
                  (value >= 216 And value <= 223) Or _
                  (value = 128) Or _
                  (value = 138) Or _
                  (value = 140) Or _
                  (value = 142) Or _
                  (value = 154) Or _
                  (value = 156) Or _
                  (value >= 158 And value <= 159) Or _
                  (value = 163) Or _
                  (value = 165)
End Function 'isUpperCase
```

Comment: This only tests the FIRST character in the string. It does not test ALL of the characters in a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function isAllUppercase(parString As String) As Boolean
    Dim lenParString As Long
    Dim pos As Long
    Dim temp As String
    lenParString = Len(parString)
    isAllUppercase = True
    For pos = 1 To lenParString
        temp = Mid(parString, pos, 1)
        If (isAlpha(temp) And isUpperCase(temp) = False) Then
            isAllUppercase = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next pos
End Function 'isAllUppercase

Function isAlpha(parString As String) As Boolean
    Dim lenParString As Integer
    Dim pos As Integer
    lenParString = Len(parString)
    For pos = 1 To lenParString
        Select Case Asc(Mid(parString, pos, 1))
            Case 65 To 90, _
                 97 To 122, _
                 138, _
                 140, _
                 142, _
                 154, _
                 156, _
                 158 To 159, _
                 192 To 214, _
                 216 To 246, _
                 249 To 255
'               65-90=A-Z, 97-122=a-z
'               138=Š, 140=Œ, 142=Ž, 154=š, 156=œ, 158=ž, 159=Ÿ, 192-214=À-Ö, 216-246=Ø-ö, 248-255=ø-ÿ
                isAlpha = True
            Case Else
                isAlpha = False
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next pos
End Function 'isAlpha

Function isUpperCase(parString As String) As Boolean
    Select Case Asc(Left(parString, 1))
        Case 65 To 90, _
             138, _
             140, _
             142, _
             159, _
             192 To 214, _
             216 To 222
'           65-90=A-Z
'           138=Š, 140=Œ, 142=Ž, 159=Ÿ, 192-214=À-Ö, 216-222=Ø-Þ
            isUpperCase = True
        Case Else
            isUpperCase = False
    End Select
End Function 'isUpperCase
```

Comment: add some context to explain how your answer will solve problem, that will really help the community in long run.

Comment: Function isAllUppercase will test all characters in the string